# Как вытащить значение атрибута из json , при большой вложенности атрибутов в PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, парсер, parse

Подскажите пожалуйста, как select -от достать из атрибута "Id": "Name"
вот это "Value": "% - 0,0040мм",
Не смог найти гуглом подходящий метод.
Переход по средствам :

json_array_elements(qualityindicators :: json -> 'Elements') -> 1 -> 'Attributes' -> 4 -> 'Value' -> 'Attributes' -> 1 ->'Value' -> 'Value'  qualityindicators

выдает значение NULL

```
{
  "ElementTypeReference": "s:PolyusMesQm/Types/QualityIndicatorResult",
  "IsDictionary": false,
  "Elements": [
    {
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "Value": {
            "Value": 120,
            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Float"
          },
          "Id": "NumericResult"
        },
        {
          "Value": {
            "Value": "120",
            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
          },
          "Id": "FormattedResult"
        },
        {
          "Value": {
            "Value": "120",
            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
          },
          "Id": "EntryResult"
        },
        {
          "Value": {
            "Attributes": [
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "744",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "Id"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "%",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "SymbolRus"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "SymbolEng"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "CodeRus"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "CodeEng"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "o:site/app/RcAppProMdm/CorporateUoms",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "ModelReference"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "4ced71db75a445aab146b254bdca88ee",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "ElementId"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "% (744)",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "ElementCode"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "o:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "Domain"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": false,
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                },
                "Id": "IsNonDeletable"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": false,
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                },
                "Id": "IsReadonly"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "2020-01-01T00:00:00+03:00",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/DateTime"
                },
                "Id": "CreationTime"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "ExpirationTime"
              }
            ],
            "DynamicAttributes": {},
            "TypeReference": "s:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom/Uom"
          },
          "Id": "Unit"
        },
        {
          "Value": {
            "Attributes": [
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "Code"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "% - 0,0071мм",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "Name"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "Description"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": true,
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                },
                "Id": "IsLocal"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "ElementTypeReference": "s:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom/Uom",
                  "IsDictionary": false,
                  "Elements": [
                    {
                      "Attributes": [
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "Id"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": "%",
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                          },
                          "Id": "SymbolRus"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "SymbolEng"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "CodeRus"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "CodeEng"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": "o:site/app/RcAppProMdm/CorporateUoms",
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                          },
                          "Id": "ModelReference"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": "4ced71db75a445aab146b254bdca88ee",
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                          },
                          "Id": "ElementId"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "ElementCode"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": "o:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom",
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                          },
                          "Id": "Domain"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": false,
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                          },
                          "Id": "IsNonDeletable"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": false,
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                          },
                          "Id": "IsReadonly"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "CreationTime"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "ExpirationTime"
                        }
                      ],
                      "DynamicAttributes": {},
                      "TypeReference": "s:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom/Uom"
                    }
                  ],
                  "ElementsDictionary": {},
                  "LookupKey": null,
                  "TypeReference": "a:s:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom/Uom"
                },
                "Id": "Units"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "ModelReference"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "ba48fa2e64ae4e4dbf88ce8ba483ca9c",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "ElementId"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "ElementCode"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "Domain"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": false,
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                },
                "Id": "IsNonDeletable"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": false,
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                },
                "Id": "IsReadonly"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "CreationTime"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "ExpirationTime"
              }
            ],
            "DynamicAttributes": {},
            "TypeReference": "s:PolyusMesQm/Domains/QmQualityIndicators/QualityIndicator"
          },
          "Id": "Indicator"
        }
      ],
      "DynamicAttributes": {},
      "TypeReference": "s:PolyusMesQm/Types/QualityIndicatorResult"
    },
    {
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "Value": {
            "Value": 100,
            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Float"
          },
          "Id": "NumericResult"
        },
        {
          "Value": {
            "Value": "100",
            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
          },
          "Id": "FormattedResult"
        },
        {
          "Value": {
            "Value": "100",
            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
          },
          "Id": "EntryResult"
        },
        {
          "Value": {
            "Attributes": [
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "744",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "Id"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "%",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "SymbolRus"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "SymbolEng"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "CodeRus"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "CodeEng"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "o:site/app/RcAppProMdm/CorporateUoms",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "ModelReference"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "4ced71db75a445aab146b254bdca88ee",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "ElementId"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "% (744)",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "ElementCode"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "o:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "Domain"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": false,
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                },
                "Id": "IsNonDeletable"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": false,
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                },
                "Id": "IsReadonly"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "2020-01-01T00:00:00+03:00",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/DateTime"
                },
                "Id": "CreationTime"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "ExpirationTime"
              }
            ],
            "DynamicAttributes": {},
            "TypeReference": "s:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom/Uom"
          },
          "Id": "Unit"
        },
        {
          "Value": {
            "Attributes": [
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "Code"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "% - 0,0040мм",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "Name"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "Description"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": true,
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                },
                "Id": "IsLocal"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "ElementTypeReference": "s:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom/Uom",
                  "IsDictionary": false,
                  "Elements": [
                    {
                      "Attributes": [
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "Id"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": "%",
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                          },
                          "Id": "SymbolRus"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "SymbolEng"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "CodeRus"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "CodeEng"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": "o:site/app/RcAppProMdm/CorporateUoms",
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                          },
                          "Id": "ModelReference"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": "4ced71db75a445aab146b254bdca88ee",
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                          },
                          "Id": "ElementId"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "ElementCode"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": "o:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom",
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                          },
                          "Id": "Domain"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": false,
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                          },
                          "Id": "IsNonDeletable"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "Value": false,
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                          },
                          "Id": "IsReadonly"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "CreationTime"
                        },
                        {
                          "Value": {
                            "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                          },
                          "Id": "ExpirationTime"
                        }
                      ],
                      "DynamicAttributes": {},
                      "TypeReference": "s:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom/Uom"
                    }
                  ],
                  "ElementsDictionary": {},
                  "LookupKey": null,
                  "TypeReference": "a:s:RcAppProMdm/Domains/Uom/Uom"
                },
                "Id": "Units"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "ModelReference"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": "89ac7aaaea13430e9fdb17f8de14fe12",
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/String"
                },
                "Id": "ElementId"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "ElementCode"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "Domain"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": false,
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                },
                "Id": "IsNonDeletable"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "Value": false,
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Boolean"
                },
                "Id": "IsReadonly"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "CreationTime"
              },
              {
                "Value": {
                  "TypeReference": "s:sys/core/types/Void"
                },
                "Id": "ExpirationTime"
              }
            ],
            "DynamicAttributes": {},
            "TypeReference": "s:PolyusMesQm/Domains/QmQualityIndicators/QualityIndicator"
          },
          "Id": "Indicator"
        }
      ],
      "DynamicAttributes": {},
      "TypeReference": "s:PolyusMesQm/Types/QualityIndicatorResult"
    }
  ],
  "ElementsDictionary": {},
  "LookupKey": null,
  "TypeReference": "a:s:PolyusMesQm/Types/QualityIndicatorResult"
}
```

Comment: проблема решилась следующим образом:                                    
     json_array_elements(qualityindicators :: json -> 'Elements') -> 'Attributes' -> 4 -> 'Value' -> 'Attributes' -> 1 ->'Value' ->> 'Value'  qualityindicators

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю более универсальный способ:

```
(SELECT Value FROM json_array_elements(ct.Value->'Attributes') as t1 
WHERE (t1.Value->>'Id')='NumericResult')->'Value'->'Value' as NumericResult,
    (SELECT Value FROM json_array_elements(
        (SELECT Value FROM json_array_elements(ct.Value->'Attributes') as t1 
         WHERE (t1.Value->>'Id')='Indicator')->'Value'->'Attributes') as t2
    WHERE (t2.Value->>'Id')='ElementId')->'Value'->>'Value' as Indicator_ElementId
FROM qualitymanagement_sample as t
INNER JOIN material_material as mm on mm.elementid =t.material
CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(t.qualityindicators::json->'Elements') as ct
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: в данном случаи сложно описать. Есть структура json, в ней происходит поиск  ключей, далее в атрибутах этого ключевого поля происходит поиск следующих ключей нужного мне атрибута. Собственно , чтобы понять смысл необходимо засунуть текстовое поле json файла в любой онлайн редактор json, например вот: jsonformatter.org